# Alt+Spacebar cool Windows 10 menu gone

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently discovered a cool menu on Windows 10 that you could summon by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> that would allow you to type in calculations, app names, google searches, etc.

Now this has switched to switching between keyboard layouts.

Can I get it back? How?

Comment: Not here. Did you install a 3rd party Tool?

Comment: @John Turns out I did : PowerToys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps thinking of the PowerToys Run search bar from Windows PowerToys? The default Hotkey should be Win+Space, but you will need to install PowerToys first if it's not installed on your computer.

[image]

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/run

Comment: Yes that's it ! I don't know why the shortcut stopped working but I changed it to something else and it's working now !